# Как получить доступ к seekbar расположенному на Notification, в стиле MediaStyle (кнопки медиаплеера + seekbar показывающий прогресс воспроизведения)

Tags: android, уведомления, seekbar

Создается уведомление в стиле MediaStyle, там соответсвенно добавляются кнопки действий медиаплеера,и имеется слайдер на котором при игре песни изменяется прогресс с периодичностью в пол секунды (обновляется Notification). При попытке тянуть ползунок слайдера происходит его перемещение до следующего обновления и положение ползунка сбрасывается. Требуется прекратить обновление Notification пока пользователь передвигает его, как только отпускает ползунок он должен дальше продолжить свое обновление. Требуется как то получить событие манипуляции с ползунком находящемся в Notification. Можно было бы переопределить колбеки, но нет доступа к seekbar котррый расположен на уведомлении.

```
private boolean isTouch;
public void setSeekbar(SeekBar seekBarPlayer) {
    seekBarPlayer.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            System.out.println("onProgressChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            isTouch = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            isTouch = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Пытался получить доступ так:

```
public SeekBar getSeekBarPlayer() {
    int topContainerId = getResources().getIdentifier("mediacontroller_progress", "id", "android");
    int identifier = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("media_controller", "layout", "android");
    View inflate = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(identifier, findViewById(identifier));
    return (SeekBar) inflate.findViewById(topContainerId);
}
```

Но он все равно события перетаскивания, касания, отпускания ползунка seekbar не обрабатывает

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проблема заключается в следующем: нужно получить событие seekbar что им пользуется пользователь, и когда это происходит прекратить обновлять позицию на seebare программно, как только пользователь уберет палец, обновление уведомления должно продолжится. Но так как у меня нет доступа к этому seekbar нельзя добавить обработчики событий: начала прикосновения и окончания

Comment: переведите пожалуйста ваш вопрос на русский язык и уточните проблему в теле вопроса

Comment: и заголовок тоже